# How to customize the LabelConnectors based on a given value - Kendo UI

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-chart

I'm trying to create a custom function to show the LabelConnectors only when a given value is less than x. Is there any way to do it?

I'm using Donut Chart with the Connectors

**Charts API** (https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/)

**LabelConnectors API**:(https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/LabelConnectors/).

As far I as saw, the Connectors are available only for all the chart.

Comment: Not that I can see through the API. I think you will have to find the DOM elements you want to hide (once the chart has rendered) and either remove them or set to style display: none. Use the browser dev tools to inspect the page to work out how to get at those elements. Doesn't look that easy in this case but is certainly possible.